# Unable to import python script from a second package

Tags: ros, python, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to import a python script which is part of a second package. The code for my project is located at https://github.com/Aditya90/zeroborgRobot/tree/feature/AddZeroborgLibrary. In the file `node_zeroborg_output.py`, I am attempting to import the `zeroborg_output.zeroborg` script which has the `ZeroBorg` class. When I try running `node_zeroborg_output`in the package `robot_motion_control`, I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named zeroborg_support.zeroborg
```

I am new to ROS, so I might be missing something obvious. Thank you for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257847/unable-to-import-python-script-from-a-second-package/) by [adi_darwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29815/adi_darwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these
> locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - the installation-dependent default.
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify `sys.path`. The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the replacement is intended. See section [Standard Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#tut-standardmodules) for more information.

In other words, the Python interpreter doesn't know where to look for your module. It looks in the directory in which  the calling file lives (your `robot_motion_control` package), then after it doesn't find it there then it looks in your `PYTHONPATH`, then the installation-dependent default. The `zeroborg_support` package is in none of these paths. Therefore, it throws an `ImportError` saying it can't find the module that you're trying to import.

Checkout the catkin docs to see [how to install Python scripts and modules](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adi_darwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29815/adi_darwin/) on 2017-03-26**:
Okay, thanks a lot for the help, I was able to figure it out based on that. I got confused earlier owing to the lack of requiring those steps in the initial package I made.